# Walking from PedEast to PedWest in Tijuana to cross into US

Tags: usa, borders, mexico

The San Ysidro Port of Entry Pedestrian West Facility (aka PedWest) pedestrian border crossing from Tijuana to San Ysidro re-opened (again) on Monday.  Yesterday my wife and a friend were using the pedestrian east crossing, which moved very slow (took close to 2 hours), and we realised later that it would probably have been much faster to use PedWest. However we have never actually attempted to walk from one to the other (on the Mexico side).

Google maps says it's about a 7 minute walk between the two entry points, however it seems to show the path going through an empty lot and down an alley.

So I just want to confirm if this is the logical and actual route to walk between the two, or is there a better route that we should be taking instead?

[image]

Related: [Obtaining or renewing I-94 at PedWest Tijuana-San Ysidro](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184725/obtaining-or-renewing-i-94-at-pedwest-tijuana-san-ysidro)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never been to Tijuana and don't have personal experience, but I see a very different image on google maps:

[image: Screenshot from google maps]

In particular, rather than "an empty lot and an alley", the route passes along a pedestrian area with some trees along the edge of a car park, leading directly to a large bridge over the highway. It looks like a much more welcoming route than on your image.

Google maps is indicating that this imagery is from 2023, so I imagine you were receiving older images for some reason, before or during construction works for the path, car park, and bridge. As I said, though, I'm not familiar with Tijuana and can't guarantee it isn't the other way around - perhaps the bridge was recently removed and you have more up-to-date images of the site during/after deconstruction (if this is the case, google hasn't noticed! the curved route doesn't correspond to any physical features visible on your screenshot, but clearly follows the bridge and path leading to it).

If the indicated route isn't suitable, the bridge on Av. Frontera (slightly south of the bridge the indicated route uses) also appears to have a pedestrian path along its edge, which looks like a suitable route only slightly longer than the indicated one.

Comment: Interesting (and werid) - my google maps still shows the image I posted, both on my computer and my phone.  But that definitely looks like a bridge over the vehicle lanes through almost to the PedWest entry, which would explain the route and suggest it's the probably the preferred way to get from one side to the other.  Will look out for it next week when we next cross the border!

Comment: @Midavalo FWIW, my Google maps shows the same route/picture as yours... However, the detailed instructions at that point do say "Take the pedestrian overpass".

Comment: @ChrisH - thank you for this photo, my wife used it yesterday and was able to navigate across to the PedWest facility.  She said if she hadn't seen the photo she would have been a bit lost as the path wasn't immediately clear.  Much appreciated