# Obtaining or renewing I-94 at PedWest Tijuana-San Ysidro

Tags: usa, borders, mexico, i-94

My wife and I often use the eastern pedestrian border crossing from Tijuana to San Ysidro, and occasionally have to stop into the permit office to renew our I-94 permissions.

On Monday the PedWest facility reopened, and we are considering using this crossing as a potentially quicker entry into the US, but are unsure how I-94's are processed here - whether we can renew them at PedWest or whether we'd still be required to use the permit office from the eastern side.

Is there facility to renew I-94 permissions at PedWest, and how do we get to it?  The only [info I was able to find online](https://www.sandiegored.com/en/news/121728/Everything-You-Need-to-Know-About-PedWest-San-Ysidros-New-Pedestrian-Port-of-Entry) was from 2016 when PedWest first opened, which mentions needing to enter the office from the *north*, which to me would be from the US side so not psosible if you can't enter the US without a current permit, and doesn't really make sense to me.

Related: [Walking from PedEast to PedWest in Tijuana to cross into US](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184723/walking-from-pedeast-to-pedwest-in-tijuana-to-cross-into-us)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My wife used the PedWest facility yesterday, and **there is no ability to obtain or renew the I-94 permit at this border crossing**.  She asked and was told that to get an I-94 she would need to use the eastern pedestrian border crossing instead.

In fact, there were CBP officers at the border gate checking every foreign passport for a current I-94 stamp before even allowing them through. I am not sure how this would have worked had there been no stamp, as is common/standard now when flying into the US, however she didn't think to ask this at the time.